# What is the best way to use a SSRS report viewer in a WPF application using MVVM

Tags: wpf, reporting-services, mvvm

I have a WPF application using MVVM. I have some user controls that show some SSRS reports in a ReportViewer control hosted within a windows forms host control.

The User Control has a simple combobox where the user selects a criteria and therefore the report satisfying this criteria will be loaded, its data fetched from the database and then the report is shown to the user.

What is the best approach to implement such scenario in WPF using MVVM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837625/using-ms-reportviewer-in-wpf/2291253#2291253)

He is creating the `WindowsFormsHost` and `ReportViewer` in the ViewModel

```
WindowsFormsHost windowsFormsHost = new WindowsFormsHost();
reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
windowsFormsHost.Child = reportViewer;
this.Viewer = windowsFormsHost
```

and then using a ContentPresenter to display it

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Viewer}" />
```

Comment: I am unable to get this.Viewer? What is Viewer here?

Comment: Viewer is a property of `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost` type

Comment: I am not able to find that property in WindowsFormsHost

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no native WPF Report Viewer control with similar functionality and there will not be one in .Net 4.0 (according to Jamie Rodriguez at Microsoft).