# Generate report/graphs/... to print in c# / WPF / .net 4

Tags: c#, printing, calendar, report, graphic

I'm doing a application to manage volunteers of a fest.

I've only one more thing to do: Generate documents which can be printed.

I'm searching something to generate theses reports.

My needs:
-Mostly print graphics calendars with some "event" in them
-Generate some letters
-Print lists

What can I use to do this?

It would be better if I can do a preview of this, but this isn't mandatory.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I'm creating my own WPF components which I print. It worked like a charm.

Comment: And Telerik Reporting seems to be greate :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb656295%28v=office.12%29.aspx

It is a technique that helps you much to generate office 2007 files! I have done a very beautiful and clean digest with it,
And it was easy and fast and free!

Except that you need a Word 2007 to edit your generated files.

For doing the calendar you can take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar

Then generate your iCal file, then import it in a calendar like google calendar or outlook or another thing that supports ical and then print it!

wish this helps

Comment: I just can't it's to print the calendar of every person which participate, so I can't go print my self 800+ calendar in outlook :/

Comment: can you clarify the layout of your calendar for each one? is it a full calendar or a set of entries with times (can be solved using a table in the office format)

Comment: Yep, Its exactly that, except that I can have very different start-stop dates, e.g. 13:49->13:53, ... on several days.
Actually my best idea is to use a calendar which is provided by telerik, and print this calendar

Comment: You can use the telerik calendar, but think of the office format, you can simply print a set of entries for your people, like a todo list. moreover be careful that you might run into problems when you use the Teleric calendar, you might have no choice to convert such calendar to pdf, etc. then you'll have to deal with an extra complexity converting that format to a printable artifact! If I was you I was going to use the docx format for it, as you see the link in my post...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend XtraReports. They look good and have helped alleviate the pain of writing my own previewer/printer/exporter, etc. See http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/index.xml

Comment: I'm doing this for free, so I just can't pay 350$ to do this :/

Comment: I understand, I was able to get the product for one of my projects and continue to use it, ... you'd be saving some of your free time in the very least up front and use it in the future for paid projects

Comment: Unfortunately, I do this for myself, not for my enterprise, and I just can't ask my enterprise to buy this for further projects :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft Report Viewer.

Helpful links:

- http://www.gotreportviewer.com/
- http://www.gotreportviewer.com/screenshots/index.html

Comment: Hi! Is it possible to create calendars with this tool? Can it works with WPF :)?

Comment: It can be used with WPF see this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837625/using-ms-reportviewer-in-wpf as for the calendar, you could lay out your report to look like one.