# C# - I have a WPF Application and im looking for Using .NET built in charts

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, charts

I have 3 parameters and i want to display them as a graph/chart such that

param 1 is red

param 2 is green

parem 3 is blue

they go in horizontal direction and vary over time something like, [**THIS GRAPH**](http://www.softsia.com/screenshots/2D-3D-Line-Graph-Software_y627.gif) how do i do it?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you got a chart to display in your application? What specifically are you having trouble with, in displaying your data?

Comment: I know silverlight has a library for charting, not sure if WPF can call that Library to use too. You may want to consider taking a look http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%202

Comment: There are charts in the WPF Toolkit. You want the line chart with the color sequence 'red-green-blue'? Also I can create dashed lines, but it requires to change source code of the toolkit, so I would use default solid lines.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the report control using a bit of Windows form interop.

take a look at [Using MS ReportViewer in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837625/using-ms-reportviewer-in-wpf).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the WPF Toolkit for free charts. Otherwise, you could use third party controls.

[WPF Toolkit Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196502/WPF-Toolkit-Charting-Controls-Line-Bar-Area-Pie-Co)

[List of chart control options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/wpf-chart-controls)