# ReportViewer in MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, reporting-services

I'm building an MVVM Light WPF app using Visual Studio 2015. The app needs to display some SQL Server Reporting Services reports locally.

The following two solutions exist:

- [Using MS ReportViewer in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837625/using-ms-reportviewer-in-wpf/)
- [Walkthrough: Using ReportViewer in a WPF Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273267.aspx)

Though the first is MVVM, it's mixing UI with the view model. The second is pure code-behind.

Here's what the first example suggests:

```
WindowsFormsHost windowsFormsHost = new WindowsFormsHost();
reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
windowsFormsHost.Child = reportViewer;
this.Viewer = windowsFormsHost
```

Note that `ReportViewer` is a UI control. The second solution uses a code-behind file:

```
private void ReportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //...
}
```

Is there a way to embed a local SSRS report into a WPF app and follow good MVVM practices? Thank you.

**Update**: No need to be fanatical! If some code-behind is needed, I'm okay with it.

Comment: UI concerns belong in the UI.  Do it in the codebehind.  MVVM != no codebehind.

Comment: Wow, is incredible nobody answered this question. :/

Comment: @Xam I got this working and will post an answer when I’m in the office tomorrow.

Comment: Alex, that would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Xam, please see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a view to select the report from a `ComboBox` and a button to run it. In the viewmodel, we have the reports' `ComboBox` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of report names and IDs. We then employ the [MVVM Light Toolkit](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight)'s `Messaging` class to send/receive "messages." Note that the base viewmodel, `MyAppViewModelBase`, inherits from Light Toolkit's `ViewModelBase`, which has the `RaisePropertyChanged()` defined.

Also note that we could pass the selected report's VM instead of the view's VM; that would be more efficient but will require modifications to this code. Then we'd use a base class for all the report VMs and a pattern-matching switch in the code-behind to select which report to run.

Here's the pertinent code for the viewmodel:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;

public class ReportsViewModel : MyAppViewModelBase
{
    public ReportsViewModel()
    {
        // Register a listener that receives the enum of the 
        // report that's ready. The message it receives has 
        // name "SsrsReportReady" with handler SsrsReportReady.
        Messenger.Default.Register<Constants.Report>(this, "SsrsReportReady", SsrsReportReady);

        // Other logic...
    }

    // Bound to a button to run the selected report
    public ICommand RunReportRelayCommand =>
                new RelayCommand(RunReport);

    // Backing field for the selected report.
    private ReportViewModel _selectedReportVm;

    public ReportViewModel SelectedReportVm
    {
        get { return _selectedReportVm; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _selectedReportVm)) return;
            _selectedReportVm = value;

            // Built-in method from Light Toolkit to 
            // handle INotifyPropertyChanged
            RaisePropertyChanged();  
        }
    }

    private void RunReport()
    {
        // Send a message called "RunSSRSReport" with this VM attached as its data.
        Messenger.Default.Send(this, "RunSSRSReport");
    }

    // Handler for report-ready
    private void SsrsReportReady(Constants.Report obj)
    {
        ShowReport = true;
        IsRunReportButtonEnabled = true;
        RunReportButtonContent = Constants.BtnGenerateReport;

        // View uses Material Design's Expander control.
        // We expand/collapse sections of the view.
        ExpandReport = true;
        ExpandParameters = false;
    }
}
```

In the code-behind of the view:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;

public partial class ReportsView : UserControl
{
    public ReportsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Register a listener for the "RunSSRSReport" 
        // message, called from our viewmodel. Its 
        // handler is RunSsrsReport and its data type 
        // is ReportsViewModel.
        Messenger.Default.Register<ReportsViewModel>(this, "RunSSRSReport", RunSsrsReport);

        DataContext = new ReportsViewModel();
    }

    // Handler to run the selected report. 
    private void RunSsrsReport(ReportsViewModel obj)
    {
        // Basic validation
        if (obj.SelectedReportVm == null || obj.SelectedReportVm.Id.Equals(-1)) 
        {
            return;
        }

        // Ugly switch to run the correct report.
        // It can be re-written with pattern matching.
        switch (obj.SelectedReportVm.Id)
        {
            case (int)Constants.Report.ReportA:
                RunReportA(obj);
                break;
            case (int)Constants.Report.ReportB:
                RunReportB(obj);
                break;
            // other reports....
        }
    }   

    // Run the report using dataset and tableadapter.
    // Modify to use your code for running the report.
    private void RunReportA(ReportsViewModel reportsViewModel)
    {
        var dataSet = new ReportADataSet();
        dataSet.BeginInit();

        // We reference the ReportViewer control in XAML.
        ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        ReportViewer.LocalReport.ShowDetailedSubreportMessages = true;
        ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        var dataSource = new ReportDataSource
        {
            Name = "ReportA_DS",
            Value = dataSet.uspReportA  // Uses a stored proc
        };
        ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
        ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource =
            "MyApp.Reports.ReportA.rdlc";
        dataSet.EndInit();
        new reportATableAdapter { ClearBeforeFill = true }
            .Fill(dataSet.uspReportA);

        // Send message back to viewmodel that the report is ready.
        Messenger.Default.Send(Constants.Report.ReportA, "SsrsReportReady");
    }
}
```

The report view has a `WindowsFormsHost` with name `ReportViewer`, referenced in above code-behind:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Width="Auto" Height="500">                   
    <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="ReportViewer" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Comment: Great. I appreciate your answer. Thanks so much!