# Microsoft Report Viewer Control in Visual Studio Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to let Microsoft report viewer control show up in Visual Studio Toolbox.
After three days of trying and reinstalling I am desperate for help. I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio Community 2019 and reportviewer (140.340.80). I believe version 15 is not showing correctly in the designer.

The report viewer MUST be there (It shows up in the toolbox if I right-click and show all). However it is greyed out and I cannot drag it to my form. I cannot drag the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll which is in my application folder (Services.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.140.340.80/packages/lib/net40) to the toolbox. I also tried creating WPF applications (Visual Basic) in different .net versions, but that did not help.

I am including pictures screenshots of my toolbox and packages.config file if that helps.

[image]
[image]

Thank you very much. I though this would be simple, but it is really frustrating.

Comment: It is a Winforms component, not happy with WPF.  Same question [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837625/using-ms-reportviewer-in-wpf).

Comment: Thank you Hans - that was it.